# How to control flow of execution in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Below is my function. It instead of calculating score, initially sends back score as 0 to caller and then later goes inside the query and calculates score but does not returns score. It simply then goes back to caller. Please help me on this.

```
function calculateScore(questionMaster,examid) {
    var score=0,arr=[];
    console.log(questionMaster);
    console.log(questionMaster[0].answers);
    console.log(questionMaster[0].answers.questionId); 
    for(var i=0;i<questionMaster[0].answers.length;i++) {
      arr[i] = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(questionMaster[0].answers[i].questionId);
    }
    console.log(arr); 
    examMasterModel.aggregate([{$match: {examid:examid}}, 
                               {$unwind: "$questionMaster"}, 
                               {$project: {questionMaster: 1 }},
                               {$match: {"questionMaster._id": {$in: arr}}}], 
                               function(err,questions){
      console.log(questions);
      for(var i=0; i<questions.length; i++) {
        if(questionMaster[0].answers[i].answer == decrypt(questions[i].questionMaster.answer)) {         {
          score++;
          console.log(questionMaster[0].answers[i].answer);
          console.log( decrypt(questions[i].questionMaster.answer));
          console.log(score);
        }
        else{
          console.log('in else');
        }
        console.log('in loop');

      }

    }); 
    return score; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`examMasterModel.aggregate` is an Asynchronous function, for which you send a callback function. Asynchronous functions' callbacks are executed at an unknown time, outside of the normal flow of your code.

What happens in your code, is that you call the async function, then return `score`, and only then your callback is executed (and changing `score` too late).

The solution is to make your `calculateScore` function asynchronous (either with getting a callback function as a parameter, or using promises), and returning the value of `score` only after it's been calculated.

***Examples***

**With callback:**

Modify your `calculateScore` function to something like:

```
function calculateScore(questionMaster, examid, callback) {
  var score = 0;
  examMasterModel.aggregate([...], function(err, questions) {
    //your logic to calculate score
    callback(score);
  });
}
```

Make sure that when you call `calculateScore`, you pass a callback function. For example:

```
calculateScore(param1, param2, function(calculatedScore) {
  score = calculatedScore;
});
```

**With promises:**

Assuming you're not using ES6, you should `npm install q` and then in your code `require('q')`. After that, the syntax is like:

```
function calculateScore(questionMaster, examid) {
  var score = 0;
  var deferred = q.defer();
  examMasterModel.aggregate([...], function(err, questions) {
    //your logic to calculate score
    deferred.resolve(score);
  });
  //note that this is in the main flow of the function, outside of the async call
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

And then you can call `calculateScore` like:

```
calculateScore(param1, param2).then(function(calculatedScore) {
  score = calculatedScore;
});
```

***Some helpful reading material:***

https://github.com/kriskowal/q

Comment: Thanks i will definitely try but can u give me a sample of it

Comment: I'll add examples to my answer

Comment: Dude but function is still returning to the caller before calculating score .

Comment: where? in which example?

Comment: In with callback. It is still returning to caller before calculating score

Comment: Did you remove the return statement from the end of the function?

Comment: Yeah dude i removed but still don't know why

Answer (score 0):

You can use Promise to control the flow

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
Promise.promisifyAll(require("mongoose"));
```

After that every function will have a async version like `aggregateAsync` which you can call like this

```
return mongoose.aggregateAsync() //....
    .then(function (resultFromAbove) {
        var score
        // do your things with score
        return score
    })
```